# jquery - get url path?

Tags: jquery, url, parsing

I know I can use window.location.pathname to return a url, but how do I parse the url?

I have a url like this: http://localhost/messages/mine/9889 and I'm trying to check to see if "mine" exists in that url?

So, if "mine" is the second piece in that url, I want to write an if statement based on that...

```
if(second argument == 'mine') { do something }
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
if ( location.pathname.split("/")[2] == "mine" ) { do something }
```

Although it would obviously be better to check whether there are enough items in the array that's returned by split:

```
var a = location.pathname.split("/");
if ( a.length > 2 && a[2] == "mine" ) { do something }
```

Note that even though array indexes are zero based, we want to specify 2 as the index to get what you refer to as the 2nd argument as split splits "/messages/mine/9889" into an array of 4 items:

```
["", "messages", "mine", "9889"]
```

Comment: Really like the simplicity of this. To remove any empty elements and have a nice array of the paths use this:
`var locationPaths = location.pathname.split("/").filter(function(n){ return n != '' });`

Answer (score 8):

if jquery is an option, you could do the following:

```
$.inArray("mine", window.location.pathname.split("/"))
```

Comment: Note that this will match _any_ 'mine', not just the one at the second part of the URL.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (window.location.pathname.split("/")[2] == "mine") {
  // it exists
};
```

window.location.pathname is a string at the end of the day, so the usual [string methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String) apply.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is a very old query.. it pops up in some search. So to add my notes.. over here

```
url.indexOf('mine') !== -1
```

The above should be used for the check to find if url has a string... where as to find the path, it would be better off to use

```js
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = url;
console.log(a.pathname);
// if url='http://localhost/messages/mine/9889'
// output will be /messages/mine/9889
```

hope this will save some ones time

Answer (score 0):

You could use the string.split('/') function to create an array of items to check otherwise there are several jQuery plugins that parse the url eg

http://projects.allmarkedup.com/jquery_url_parser/