# How to get the extension of an url

Tags: jquery

I need to get the extension of the URL, for example(.xhtml) using jQuery?

Comment: And what about the url like you have for this page? There is no extension in it.

Comment: clearly he's not referring to that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-jquery) - it describes how to get the current URL using JQuery. Getting the extension would be relatively simple after that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ext = window.location.pathname.split('.').pop();
});
```

Other [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668005/jquery-get-url-path) also show how to use the path.

Answer (score 8):

jQuery doesn't come into play here.

If you can guarantee your URL ends with an extension...

```
var path = window.location.pathname,
    ext = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
```

...or...

```
var ext = window.location.pathname.split('.').pop();
```

...otherwise this will return the full path. You could fix that by making it a bit more verbose...

```
var path = window.location.pathname.split('.'),
    ext;

if (path.length > 1) {
    ext = path.pop();
}
```