# How to get the url path from a referring url

Tags: jquery

I have a var that captures the referring URL:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var referrer =  document.referrer;
   console.log(referrer);
});
```

Assuming the url is `http://www.example.com/this/is/my/path` how can I set `referrer` = `/this/is/my/path` where the actual host domain may be variable? E.g. I want to use this on difference domains.

**Update**

This answer: [jquery - get url path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668005/jquery-get-url-path) does not help as it's a solution that uses location.pathname.split not the referrer, and also splits the path based on a string not capturing it completely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery - get url path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668005/jquery-get-url-path)

Comment: that's solution uses `location.pathname.split` not the referrer, and also splits the path based on a string not capturing it completely.

Comment: really not clear what your goal is with regard to different domains. This sounds like an `X-Y` problem. What is higher level objective?

Comment: The process is the same for any URL. I'm not clear on how your question is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `window.location` object has the following properties considering the exmaple referrer

```
document.referrer; 
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668005/jquery-get-url-path#footer"
```

`location:{`

```
  hash: "#footer"
  host: "stackoverflow.com"
  hostname: "stackoverflow.com"
  href: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668005/jquery-get-url-path#footer"
  origin: "http://stackoverflow.com"
  pathname: "/questions/2668005/jquery-get-url-path"
  port: "" 
  protocol: "http:"
```

`}`

You can use `location.pathname`, and the empty default http port is 80