# How to set path of file in website root for use by jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I use jquery-style-switcher.js for change style some of   elements.In this case i must specify the full path of style sheet files in root website.In the page source of this page another css files has link such as this:

```
/dnn_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/style.css
```

and I use this full path for switcher

```
 fullPath: '/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/'
```

But when run website switcher can not load the files.Please advice.

Comment: The name of the property, `fullPath`, would indicate that it want's a full path - not a relative one. I'm just guessing though.

Comment: Now How to set full path in localhost  or host?

Comment: @programmer138200 If your server is case-sensitive, try changing `dnn_test` portion to match the other and vice versa. i.e. `DNN_test` or `dnn_test`.

Comment: I try set path via localhost .I use this path : file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/  ----->but don't worked .Now How to set full path in localhost  or host?

Comment: Usually localhost is `http://127.0.0.1/` you might have a port as well `http://127.0.0.1:80/` the port number varies 80 being default.

Comment: I use this path : http://127.0.0.1/C:/inetpub/wwwroot/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/    &&&&  http://127.0.0.1/file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/  -----> but don't worked

Comment: Get rid of the `C:/` and `file:///C:/`

Comment: No this is not work !

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/`

Comment: don't solved     .. .

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this :

If you are using PHP and any other language. just get webroot path in PHP and echo that in html tag and get that html tag value using javascript.

Example :

You can also write static URL in href attribute.

Write Code in html file :

```
<base style="display:none" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];?>">
```

Write code in jquery file :

```
var baseUrl = $('base').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `window.location` object has the following properties :

considering the exmaple referrer :

```
document.referrer; 
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668005/jquery-get-url-path#footer"

 location:{

  hash: "#footer"
  host: "stackoverflow.com"
  hostname: "stackoverflow.com"
  href: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668005/jquery-get-url-path#footer"
  origin: "http://stackoverflow.com"
  pathname: "/questions/2668005/jquery-get-url-path"
  port: "" 
  protocol: "http:"
 }
```

You can use `location.pathname`, and the empty default http port is 80

For jquery use :

Tyr to remove `/` from the `'/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/'` so it will look like:

```
DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/
```

Comment: yes, but you can put php variable in between jquery

Comment: @BhavinSolanki Do you have any references? I'm interested to know more about this.

Comment: try my updated answer , this will sure solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you probably use linux and paths are case-sensitive in linux so use this path and tell us the result:

```
/dnn_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/css/
```