# Error on change style of page with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, dotnetnuke-7

I use `jquery-style-switcher.js` for changing style of some elements. When I click on the colors style of page doesn't change and in source of this page added this class`jssError error level0` to `ul` tag that contain colors. This codes worked in HTML page but in CMS no!
I debug this js file by chrome  and understand that When  this js file on the general html file runed : an event call it **addClickEvents** executed but in my website that used this template for skin of website : **addClickEvents** function don't executed. Function that call addClickEvents is **init** function

```
    init: function ($root, config) {
        this.$root = $root;
        this.config = config ? config : {};
        this.setDefaultTheme();
        if(this.defaultTheme) {
            // try cookies
            if (this.config.cookie) {
                this.checkCookie();
            }
            // try hover
            if (this.config.hasPreview) {
                this.addHoverEvents();
            }
            // finally, add click events
            this.addClickEvents();
        } else {
            this.$root.addClass('jssError error level0');
        }
    }
```

In this function(init) : **defaultTheme value is undefined !!!!**

Why defaultTheme is undefined ? if you can  answer this question , The problem will be solved.

[Github link](https://github.com/camsjams/jquery-style-switcher)

**jquery-style-switcher.js :**

```
(function ($) {
    var jStyleSwitcher,
        _defaultOptions = {
            hasPreview: true,
            defaultThemeId: 'jssDefault',
            fullPath: 'css/',
            cookie: {
                expires: 30,
                isManagingLoad: true
            }
        },
        // private
        _cookieKey = 'jss_selected',
        _docCookies = {};

    /*\
    |*|
    |*|  :: cookies.js ::
    |*|
    |*|  A complete cookies reader/writer framework with full unicode support.
    |*|
    |*|  revision #1
    |*|
    |*|  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie
    |*|
    |*|  This framework is released under the GNU Public License, version 3 or later.
    |*|  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0-standalone.html
    |*|
    |*|  Syntaxes:
    |*|
    |*|  * docCookies.setItem(name, value[, end[, path[, domain[, secure]]]])
    |*|  * docCookies.getItem(name)
    |*|  * docCookies.removeItem(name[, path[, domain]])
    |*|  * docCookies.hasItem(name)
    |*|  * docCookies.keys()
    |*|
    \*/
    _docCookies = {
        getItem: function (sKey) {
            if (!sKey) {
                return null;
            }
            return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
        },
        setItem: function (sKey, sValue, vEnd, sPath, sDomain, bSecure) {
            if (!sKey || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(sKey)) {
                return false;
            }
            var sExpires = "";
            if (vEnd) {
                switch (vEnd.constructor) {
                    case Number:
                        sExpires = vEnd === Infinity ? "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" : "; max-age=" + vEnd;
                        break;
                    case String:
                        sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd;
                        break;
                    case Date:
                        sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd.toUTCString();
                        break;
                }
            }
            document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(sValue) + sExpires + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "") + (bSecure ? "; secure" : "");
            return true;
        },
        removeItem: function (sKey, sPath, sDomain) {
            if (!this.hasItem(sKey)) {
                return false;
            }
            document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "");
            return true;
        },
        hasItem: function (sKey) {
            if (!sKey) {
                return false;
            }
            return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
        },
        keys: function () {
            var aKeys = document.cookie.replace(/((?:^|\s*;)[^\=]+)(?=;|$)|^\s*|\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?(?:\1|$)/g, "").split(/\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?;\s*/);
            for (var nLen = aKeys.length, nIdx = 0; nIdx < nLen; nIdx++) {
                aKeys[nIdx] = decodeURIComponent(aKeys[nIdx]);
            }
            return aKeys;
        }
    };

    jStyleSwitcher = function ($root, config) {
        return this.init($root, config);
    };

    jStyleSwitcher.prototype = {

        /**
         * {Object} DOM reference to style option list
         */
        $root: null,

        /**
         * {Object} configs for the style switcher
         */
        config: {},

        /**
         * {Object} jQuery reference to <link> tag for swapping CSS
         */
        $themeCss: null,

        /**
         * {String} default theme page was loaded with
         */
        defaultTheme: null,

        init: function ($root, config) {
            this.$root = $root;
            this.config = config ? config : {};
            this.setDefaultTheme();
            if(this.defaultTheme) {
                // try cookies
                if (this.config.cookie) {
                    this.checkCookie();
                }
                // try hover
                if (this.config.hasPreview) {
                    this.addHoverEvents();
                }
                // finally, add click events
                this.addClickEvents();
            } else {
                this.$root.addClass('jssError error level0');
            }
        },

        setDefaultTheme: function () {
            this.$themeCss = $('link[id=' + this.config.defaultThemeId + ']');
            if(this.$themeCss.length) {
                this.defaultTheme = this.$themeCss.attr('href');
            }
        },

        resetStyle: function() {
            this.updateStyle(this.defaultTheme);
        },

        updateStyle: function(newStyle) {
            this.$themeCss.attr('href', newStyle);
        },

        getFullAssetPath: function(asset) {
            return this.config.fullPath + asset + '.css';
        },

        checkCookie: function () {
            var styleCookie;
            // if using cookies and using JavaScript to load css
            if (this.config.cookie && this.config.cookie.isManagingLoad) {
                // check if css is set in cookie
                styleCookie = _docCookies.getItem(_cookieKey);
                if (styleCookie) {
                    newStyle = this.getFullAssetPath(styleCookie);
                    // update link tag
                    this.updateStyle(newStyle);
                    // update default ref
                    this.defaultTheme = newStyle;
                }
            }
        },

        addHoverEvents: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.$root.find('a').hover(
                function () {
                    var asset = $(this).data('theme'),
                        newStyle = self.getFullAssetPath(asset);
                    // update link tag
                    self.updateStyle(newStyle);
                },
                function () {
                    // reset link tag
                    self.resetStyle();
                }
            );
        },

        addClickEvents: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.$root.find('a').click(
                function () {
                    var asset = $(this).data('theme'),
                        newStyle = self.getFullAssetPath(asset);
                    // update link tag
                    self.updateStyle(newStyle);
                    // update default ref
                    self.defaultTheme = newStyle;
                    // try to store cookie
                    if (self.config.cookie) {
                        _docCookies.setItem(_cookieKey, asset, self.config.cookie.expires, '/');
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    };

    $.fn.styleSwitcher = function (options) {
        return new jStyleSwitcher(this, $.extend(true, _defaultOptions, options));
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**HTML of this section in my page :**

```
<div id="colour-variations">
        <a class="option-toggle"><i class="icon-gear"></i></a>
        <h3>Preset Colors</h3>
        <ul class="jssError error level0">
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="style"></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="pink"></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="blue"></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="turquoise"></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="orange"></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="lightblue"></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="brown"></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" data-theme="green"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

[image]

You can see [template](http://freehtml5.co/demos/crew/) that is general website. I use this template in skin for `dotnetnuke7` and this problem appeared.

[Download My codes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B13lB0g6pfmceUViT215b3VtMnM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please post the code in a snippet ([See illustration](http://i.imgur.com/p94EZRA.png?1)), [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net), [PenCode.io](http://pencode.io), or [Plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co)

In addition, you should refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Include your color themes as well `style.css`, `pink.css` ... `green.css`

Comment: Also need the `default.css`. You have problems with this plugin that switches styles, yet you provide no CSS at all. What rules do these classes have? `jssError`, `error`,  `level0`, `colour-variations`, `option-toggle`, etc.. This img shows us nothing about the underlying code.

Comment: Now You  can see general template .I use this template in my website that is in localhost and dnn7 cms.

Comment: I think that problem is path of css files because I use this template in skin of CMS  .I discussed in this page ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455685/how-to-set-path-of-file-in-website-root-for-use-by-jquery ) but don't solved.

Comment: You tried the solutions from [Monty](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34456024/2813224) and [Bhavin Solanki](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34455920/2813224)? Won't it be impossible for you to use this plugin without the proper reference your path?

Comment: Couldn't you create a directory then place your assets there? You should be able to reference an assets folder that's placed wherever your webpage is placed. Is dotnuke totally different than what I think it is?

Comment: If I want change  the full path with windows.location or base url href : How to change jquery-style-switcher.js?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98999/discussion-between-zer00ne-and-programmer138200).

Answer (score 1):

You've almost made it work, just a few things to fix here.

These steps apply to the files from your "Download My codes" archive.

---

First, while handling click on color theme square icons, your code throws this JS error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

In your `main.js`, change `clickMenu` function. Wrap a call to `$('html, body').animate` in a condition that `section` must be defined.

```
var clickMenu = function() {

    $('a:not([class="external"])').click(function(event){
        var section = $(this).data('nav-section'),
            navbar = $('#navbar');

        if(section){ // <- this wrap condition 
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('[data-section="' + section + '"]').offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }

        if ( navbar.is(':visible')) {
            navbar.removeClass('in');
            navbar.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
            $('.js-fh5co-nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
        }

        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

};
```

---

Second, in your `switcher.html`, on line 799, you've left (probably intentionally) `"jssError error level0"` classes on `ul` inside `#colour-variations` element:

```
<ul class="jssError error level0">
...
</ul>
```

So remove these classes:

```
<ul>
...
</ul>
```

---

And a final little thing: add that `<link>` somewhere in the `<head>`:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="theme-switch" href="style.css">
```

It is required for plugin to initialize correctly. Absence of this line was the reason you got `"jssError error level0"` error.

---

I've also made a [.zip with working code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9gxw1JTB2IULWQxRTRwbURqdTQ/view?usp=sharing). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to add it on an event, you can do so easily as well.

```
$(".first").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("second");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is `setDefaultTheme()` function

```
            this.$themeCss = $('link[id=' + this.config.defaultThemeId + ']');
            if(this.$themeCss.length) {
                this.defaultTheme = this.$themeCss.attr('href');
            }
```

And this is where `defaultThemeId` is set

```
_defaultOptions = {
            hasPreview: true,
            defaultThemeId: 'jssDefault',
            fullPath: 'css/',
            cookie: {
                expires: 30,
                isManagingLoad: true
            }
        },
```

You on your `head` you need to add something like

```
<link id="jssDefault" href="{your default theme here}" />
```

So it can set your default theme correctly.