# Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why am I getting this error on my code?

> Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined`

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var currentPage = jQuery.url.attr("path");
    $(':input').blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            pageTracker._trackEvent("Form: " + currentPage, "input_exit", $(this).attr('name'));
        } 
    });
});
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ocdcqrf/

Comment: jQuery.url is undefined  if you do a console log(jQuery.url) you will see it's undefined

Comment: What is `jQuery.url`? Are you using a 3rd party library as that's not a a standard property. What value are you expecting it to return. By default it will return `undefined`, hence calling `attr()` on that is throwing the error.

Comment: I don't think `.attr` is one of `$.url`'s methods.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback/ I'm using this tutorial here: https://www.distilled.net/blog/conversion-rate-optimization/using-jquery-and-google-analytics-events-to-track-form-abandonment/

Comment: From that guide: `I’ve also used a jquery url parser, the installation of which was very simple`. They link to the guide, but it 404s. That's the issue; you're missing that library.

Comment: I believe the OP needs to make use of this library: https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a console log on **jQuery.url**, you will see  this is has a value of undefined.

you will needd to use **location.pathname** instead of **jQuery.url**.

Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668005/jquery-get-url-path) for proper understanding

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `jQuery.url` is undefined. I'm not sure where you even got the idea that this property should exist, since it's not part of jQuery. To get the actual current page, you can simply get the native property

```
window.location.href
```